# IPSec What is IKE Phase 2 brining?

Tags: security, networking, vpn, ipsec

I am learning basis IPSec, and the Ike Phase 1 and 2 concept.

I understand there is a decoupling of phases because it allows to establish a heavy phase 1 once, and multiple light phase 2 as often as needed.
What I don't understand is what phase 2 actually bringing to security.

Once IKE Phase 1 is completed, both machines have exchange a private key. Why is not every following communication not using that key? Why is there a second exchange of key?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK the reason for that is rekeying (as you need to limit the amount of data encrypted with a particular key + and limit the time the particular key is used). See [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5996#section-2.8).